# .Net Core ActionResult<bool> always returning false?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating an API server, i'm using a service to verify certain inputs, it's methods return ActionResult, this is so that i can either return a 403/404/200 result if the value is false. When my methods return this value it seems that the result.Value is always false?

I've attempted to just simply check if an ActionResult is status code 200 and skip the  part, however there doesn't seem to be a way to do so (that seems correct)

Verification Method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> CanUpdateUser(ClaimsPrincipal user, Organisation org, string userId)
{
    if (org == null)
        return StatusCode(404, ApiResponseConstants.OrganisationDoesntExist);

    if (!org.UserIsMember(user))
        return StatusCode(403, ApiResponseConstants.NotOrganisationMember);

    if (!org.UserHasPermission(user, OrganisationPermissions.EditOrgUsers))
        return StatusCode(403, ApiResponseConstants.NoPermission);

    ResponseUser responseUser = await GetResponseUserAsync(org, userId);
    if (responseUser == null)
        return StatusCode(404, ApiResponseConstants.UserDoesntExist);

    if (userId.Equals(org.Owner, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return StatusCode(403, "Organisation owners cannot be updated");

    string currentUserId = user.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type.Equals("sub")).Value;
    return userId.Equals(currentUserId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? StatusCode(403, "Organisation users cannot update themselves") : Ok(true);
}

private static OkObjectResult Ok(object value)
{
    return new OkObjectResult(value);
}

private static ObjectResult StatusCode(int statusCode, object value)
{
    return new ObjectResult(value)
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode
    };
}
```

Controller method using Verification method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> CanUpdateUser(string organisation, string user, bool respond200 = true)
{
    Organisation org = await _verificationService.VerifyOrganisation(organisation);
    ActionResult<bool> result = await _canUserService.CanUpdateUser(User, org, user);
    return respond200 ? Ok(result.Value) : result;
}
```

I would expect that `result.Value == true` when i do `Ok(true)` however it's false? If i put a debugger breakpoint in the StatusCode method the `ObjectResult.Value == true` so there's something strange going on here between the two methods?

EDIT:

As a note, i'm using .Net Core 2.2

Comment: You're actually getting the default value of the `Value` property an instance of `ActionResult<bool>` because you're converting an `ObjectResult` to an `ActionResult<bool>`, which uses its default constructor.

Comment: @HereticMonkey in Debugger view the object is actually an ObjectResult instance, as ObjectResult extends ActionResult, either way, it behaves the same way if i return ObjectResult instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your logic is wrong in this line of code

```
 return userId.Equals(currentUserId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? StatusCode(403, "Organisation users cannot update themselves") : Ok(true);
```

Instead try to change to this to see if it work

```
 return userId.Equals(currentUserId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? StatusCode(403, "Organisation users cannot update themselves") : true;
```

Comment: That's extremely interesting, that works, however if you're able to answer, why is it that Ok(true) doesn't work, however something like Ok(org) does (org being a simple object with string values and such)

Comment: Because you are using `Ok()` status code response that only exist in controller

Comment: Sorry, edited my question with the code for my Ok() method, it's identical to the Base Controller code, however it returns false.

Comment: Yes I think is ok